# How to debug the cartridge scripts in Openshift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I want to develop a new cartridge for my own use. I use OpenShift Cartridge Development Kit to start my work. My building script is written in .openshift/action_hooks/build and it can be successfully executed.

But when I tried to use the command displayed on the homepage of the CDK project - "rhc create-app mynewcart http://##YOUR-DOMAIN##/manifest/##YOUR-COMMIT-ID##" - to create an app, I got the following error:  "Unable to complete the requested operation due to: An invalid exit code (1) was returned from the server ex-std-node161.prod.rhcloud.com.  This indicates an unexpected problem during the
execution of your request."

How can I trace the progress of deploying and find out where is the code that caused the problem? Is there any log file available for me to analyse?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--debug` option when running the command and you'll get much more detailed output:

```
rhc create-app mynewcart http://##YOUR-DOMAIN##/manifest/##YOUR-COMMIT-ID## --debug
```